# How to include a custom SQL function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `find_by_sql` to execute an SQL query.
I would like to be able to use Soundex and Levenshtein, but in order to use Levenshtein I need to include the function as a file.

This is my code so far:

```
info = params[:email].split('@')
name = info[0]
domain = info[1]

levenshtein = File.open("./lib/assets/mysql-function-levenshtein.sql")

results = Domain.find_by_sql(
    "" + levenshtein + "
    SELECT *
    FROM domains
    WHERE domain = '" + domain + "'"
)
```

I have no idea if simply including it in the query is even valid.

What's the best implementation?

By the way the file I'm trying to include is this:
https://github.com/vyper/levenshtein-sql

Comment: Have you tried running that? I'd probably use `File.read` instead of `File.open`, or wrap the `find_by_sql` call in a `File.open do ... end` block. Otherwise I'm not overly fond of using custom SQL queries. Couldn't you just define the function on the database, and do a `where("levensthtein('leonardo', 'leonardu')")`? There's no real need to define the function every time you run the query, right?

Comment: Yeah you're right, `File.read` is the one to use.

Comment: How would I go about defining the function on the database?

Comment: See my answer for putting the function in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, I think you'd be better off just defining that function in your database with a migration, so you wouldn't have to define it again for every query where you want to use it:

```
class AddLevenShteinFunctionToDatabase < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    levenshtein = File.read("/path/to/levenshtein.sql")
    execute levenshtein
  end

  def down
    # maybe put some code here to delete the function
  end
end
```

With this done, you could also add a scope to your `Domain` model for doing these kind of queries:

```
scope :levenshtein, lambda {|s1, s2| select("levenshein(#{s1}, #{s2})") }
```

With this, you should be able to write your queries something like this:

```
results = Domain.levenshtein("LEONARDO", "LEONARDU").where(:domain => domain)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm worried that using Active Record will have an impact on performance. There will be many requests per second, and I've been told that executing raw SQL will prove much faster.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend that you write a benchmark test for checking whether that is indeed the case, and if so, just use `Domain.find_by_sql("select levenshtein('#{s1}', '#{s2}') from domains where domain = '#{domain}')` instead.

Comment: Thanks, am I able to use this stored function with `find_by_sql`?

Comment: That's my assumption. If not, my answer would be pretty useless.

Comment: I'm receiving this error when running the migration: `undefined local variable or method 'levenshtein' for #<AddLevenshteinFunctionToDatabase:0xb70b1d34>`

Comment: That's because I misspelled the variable when I initialized it in the example. It should be `levenshtein = ...`, not `levensthein = ...`. This has been edited.

Comment: In case anyone else is wanting to use Levenshtein, the easiest option is to use the `Text` gem: https://github.com/threedaymonk/text
The SQL function I tried to include above was giving me errors.

Comment: That may well be, but that gem solves the problem in ruby, which probably will be a lot slower than doing it in sql, and if performance is important, you might want to look into what version is faster, provided of course that you'll be able to make the SQL version work.